# project from a n-dimensional space to 2-dim

Tags: projection, plotting

let's say that I have a sphere in $N$-dimensions

$$x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_N^2=R$$

If I want to know the projection on the $x_1-x_2$ plane in this case I can figure out myself that is a circle, but how can I get Mathematica to do the projection and plot it for me?

Of course I need to apply this to a more complicated case where the N-dimensional surface is not as simple and can only be defined implicitly by $f(x_1,...,x_N)=0$.

I hope I have not forgot too much math from school that I am asking mathematica to do this for me.

Comment: Actually it's a disk in this case. (You probably realize that but, if not, the difference is important.)

Comment: Can you give an example of an actual function you plan to work with?  The $n$-sphere is trivial, but your actual problem might still have some structure to it that will make it easier to solve than the completely general case.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using `FindInstance` and `RegionPlot`. Unfortunately it is *incredibly* slow.

A funky function for us to test on:

```
f[x_, y_, z_, w_] := Sin[x] Cos[y] + Sin[y] Cos[z] + Sin[z] Cos[w] + Sin[w] Cos[x] - 1
```

Check whether a point $(x,y)$ corresponds to a solution $f(x,y,z,w)=0$ for some $z$ and $w$:

```
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Length@FindInstance[f[x, y, z, w] == 0, {z, w}, Reals] > 0
```

Plot the region where $g(x,y)$ is `True`:

```
RegionPlot[g[x, y], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotPoints -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

[image]

Even with `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` turned way down it takes like ten minutes to create the plot.

Comment: Why not `ContourPlot[f[x, y, 0, 0] == 0, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}]` ?

Comment: My understanding of the question is we want the projection of the entire set $f(x,y,z,w)=0$ onto the $xy$ plane, not a slice through the $xy$ plane. That is, if $f(1,1,1,1)=0$ then $(1,1)$ should be included in the plot even if $f(1,1,0,0)\ne0$.

Comment: As said by Rahul I need not to just plot a slice, but the entire projection. For the N-sphere it would be a filled circle, not the perimeter of a circumference of some radius. The `FindInstance` is a good function to think about for this issue and the proposed example is at least food for thoughts, thanks.

Comment: I see that the function gets incredibly slower as the number of dimensions increases. I am wondering if putting some more information in the game could help. For instance my function is Likelyhood, so I know that there is a maximum at a given point that is contained in the area that will result from the projection. I was thinking to use this information by drawing the projection with a random shot of points starting from a seed based of the location of the maximum point. This, I think, should scale much more friendly when one increases the number of dimensions that are projected out.

Comment: `Show@Table[
  ContourPlot[f[x, y, z, w] == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}], {z, -3, 
   3, .3}, {w, -3, 3, .3}]` gives some hints about the shape and it's much faster.  Of course it's far from precise ...